# DB2- fetching records having products in more than one store

Tags: db2, mainframe

I have a table having records as below

store num     product no.

0001                       11

0002                       11

0003                       11

0001                       12

0002                       12

0001                       13

I want to fetch  records  having products in more than one store. The result should be like below

store num     product no.

0001                         11

0002                         11

0003                         11

0001                         12

0002                         12

The last record should not be there since product is in only one store.

Please help?

Comment: You should perhaps tag this 'sql', because it's a generic SQL problem. And it's really got nothing to do with mainframes.

Comment: @Tom, that's not _entirely_ true. If it is indeed DB2/z instead of DB2/LUW, there are subtle differences in the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to call your table 'availability'. I did the following with PostgreSQL, but it's standard SQL, and i believe DB2 has excellent support for standard SQL, and will handle these just fine.

Here's the way that feels most natural to me:

```
select *
from availability
where product_no in (
    select product_no
    from availability
    group by product_no
    having count(*) > 1
);
```

If you'd prefer that as a correlated subquery:

```
select *
from availability a
where (
    select count(*)
    from availability
    where product_no = a.product_no
) > 1;
```